# How to create dummy variables in R based on multiple values within each cell in a column

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I have  a dataset called cookbooks4 that currently looks like this

```
SectionTitle     Author            Work            PubYear            Item
Albertine        Susan Markovitz   The salad book  1928       pear,cream cheese,lettuce, vinegar
```

The dataset is long I just included the first line, but as you can imagine, each recipe has its own ingredients. I would need to create dummy variables for the Item (ingredients). I would like to select all unique ingredients and put them in a column. I should obtain something that looks like this. Bear in mind that this is the first line and I should have roughly 630 different in gredients (so 630 different columns for dummy variables). After cream I might have ingredients that are not listed in the item column of that specific recipe so the dummy would be 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
SectionTitle     Author            Work   PubYear       Item       pear   cream   ....
Albertine        Susan...   The salad..    1928    pear,cream...   1       1
```

I did try this but I get an error message. Plus I would need to keep also all the other columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
final <- strsplit(cookbooks4$Item, split = ",")
Item <- unique(str_trim(unlist(t)))
final2 <- as.data.frame(Reduce(cbind, lapply(Item, function(i) sapply(t, function(j) +(any(grepl(i, j), na.rm = TRUE))))))
names(final2) <- item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- data.frame(SectionTitle = "Albertine", Author = "Susan Markovitz", 
    Work = "The salad book", PubYear = 1928L, Item = "pear,cream,cheese,lettuce,vinegar")

data %>% mutate(Itemlist = strsplit(Item,",")) %>% unnest(Itemlist) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Itemlist, values_from = Itemlist, values_fn = length)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 10
#>   SectionTitle Author     Work  PubYear Item   pear cream cheese lettuce vinegar
#>   <chr>        <chr>      <chr>   <int> <chr> <int> <int>  <int>   <int>   <int>
#> 1 Albertine    Susan Mar… The …    1928 pear…     1     1      1       1       1
```

Comment: Is there a way to assign 0 instead of NA to all the dummies?

Comment: Add the argument `values_fill = 0` to `pivot_wider`.